# Google analytics : Execute API with authentication

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

As per the [querybuilder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

My API URI looks:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:12134345&
   start-date=30daysAgo
   &end-date=yesterday&
   metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:pageValue,ga:entrances&
   dimensions=ga:pagePath,ga:daysSinceLastSession,ga:sessionCount,ga%3
   Abrowser,ga:city&filters=ga:pagePath==/home
```

> But when i execute in my domain, it throws error as **login
>   required**. So for that i also passed API-KEY as `&key="****"` to the
>   above url. But still no success. Still i get the same error

Am i missing something? Can i embed this results to embed-api in charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api key is different from the access token. If you use the Query Explorer you can check a box in the report to include the access token in the query URI, which will allow you to just paste it into your browser's address bar (note: access tokens expire after an hour).

If you want to learn how to get an access token programmatically, you should check out the OAuth 2.0 section of the Google Developers site:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: can we embed this with Embed API?

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe ask a separate question and link it here?

Comment: I mean: from the results of Query Explorer, can we present in the form of charts integrating with Embed API or do we want to create charts with our own as their is a bunch of data coming...

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but the Query Explorer itself is built using the Embed API, so anything you can do with the Query Explorer can obviously be done with the Embed API too.

Comment: Thanks @Philip Walton, Last Question: In the query builder once we execute the query. Results are displayed as report in table. So which chart are they using for that. How to integrate the same with our code?

Comment: It's the table chart. Here's the [code](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/master/src/javascript/query-explorer/data-chart.js#L33), and here's the Embed API [chart type option documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#datachart).